# How to get control of the Headers in the Pivot.HeaderTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a pivot with a Header template, I want to access the headers from c# and then do some manipulations on them.
But unfortunately I can't get direct access to them.

Code :

```
<Pivot x:Name="mainContentPivot"  Grid.Row="1"
       ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CategoriesPivotItemsStyle}"
       >
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleHeaders}" FontSize="16" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

How do I access the individual Header's that are created after the Pivot is bound to an itemsSource?

Edit: My main aim here I wanted to override the Pivot arrows to act as paging since I have a lot of PivotItems more than that can be displayed on the screen at once. Hence when a user taps on the next pivot arrow I would like to skip all the PivotItems which are visible and go to next PivotItem which can't be seen in the view.

In order to do this I thought I need to calculate the size of the header's (since different headers are of different sizes) and then with the help of this I would get to know how many PivotItem's are current shown in the view and based on which I can select the next PivotItem.

Comment: Could you detail what is  exactly TitleHeaders? (c# side).

Comment: Its just a string type which is the header. It displays perfectly. It's just I need a reference to the headers from c#

Comment: You bind the data to the pivot's header, you know all the data in pivot's header. Why you want access them?  Commonly we access the header in code behind because the header's data is binding in xaml. So please give the detail requirement of what thing you want to get from the headers and what you want do with this header, with these maybe  we can give you a demo.

Comment: @Sunteen : Edited the question to add more info as to what I'm trying to achieve. Also I've tried using FindElementInVisualTree, but I could only get the current Header in this case.

Comment: I would be using the ActualWidth in this case. Yeah I know a user can do that but this is for an application which will be used very frequently hence the I would like to cut down the two operations required to one.